# Invalid Parameter Error for getBalance() in FA 1.2 Token

Tags: taquito

We are working for FA 1.2 Tokens with the

*Ref Link:* [https://assets.tqtezos.com/docs/token-contracts/fa12/2-fa12-ligo/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFNf2.png)

and got stuck at this point.

**Code Used:**

```
const op = await contract.methods
      .getBalance(
        "tz1WBCcuxGrKagQRCSYVg3qQvDoRMrGaMaa2"
        // "KT1TjdF4H8H2qzxichtEbiCwHxCRM1SVx6B7"
      )
      .send();
```

Can anyone help us?

**Error reference**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the balance of the contract, you should directly look in its storage. What you are doing now is calling an entry point which will cause the contract to call another contract and pass its balance as as an input. There are circumstances where this might be what you want but, in that case, you will need to pass two parameters, one being the key your are querying and the other being which contract the FA1.2 contract should call with that result.

Comment: Input: looking for balance in storage:

`console.log("Storage", contract.storage);`

Got the Output:
**Storage** 
`function () {}

<constructor>: "Function"

name: "Function"`

Can you help me with example.